# How to fix the error TypeError (no implicit conversion of nil into String): lib/json_web_token.rb:5:in `encode'?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, authentication, heroku, jwt

I have a simple Jwt Authentication works perfectly on local environment, but when uploaded to heroku gives the following error!

TypeError (no implicit conversion of nil into String): lib/json_web_token.rb:5:in `encode'

how do i take care of this?

This is my lib/json_web_token.rb

```
class JsonWebToken
 class << self
   def encode(payload, exp = 24.hours.from_now)
     payload[:exp] = exp.to_i
     JWT.encode(payload, Rails.application.secrets.secret_key_base)
   end

   def decode(token)
     body = JWT.decode(token, Rails.application.secrets.secret_key_base)[0]
     HashWithIndifferentAccess.new body
   rescue
     nil
   end
 end
end
```

Comment: Either payload or  Rails.application.secrets.secret_key_base is nil.   In Rails 5.3    Rails.application.secrets.secret_key_base has become Rails.application.credentials.secret_key_base. Are you using the same version of rails locally and on Heroku?

Comment: I tried with both of those statements i still get the same error!

Comment: you could work out which is nil by adding some code to raise a more specific error, then from there you will have more to go on.  something like:  raise StandardError.new("payload is nil") unless payload /  raise StandardError.new("secret key is nil") unless  Rails.application.secrets.secret_key_base.  This will not fix your code but will give you a more specific error

Answer (score 1):

Try like this:

```
require 'jwt'

class JsonWebToken
 def self.encode(payload, expiration = Rails.application.secrets.jwt_expiration_seconds.to_i.seconds.from_now)
   payload = payload.dup
   payload[:exp] = expiration.to_i
   JWT.encode(payload, Rails.application.secrets.hmac_secret_key)
 end

 def self.decode(token)
   JWT.decode(token, Rails.application.secrets.hmac_secret_key)
 rescue JWT::ExpiredSignature, JWT::DecodeError
   false
 end

 def self.decode_to_payload(token)
   decode(token).first.except('exp').with_indifferent_access
 end
end
```

I hope that work for you.

Answer (score 1):

Replace `Rails.application.secrets.secret_key_base` with `ENV['SECRET_KEY_BASE']` in both the `encode` and `decode` methods.

The `SECRET_KEY_BASE` environment variable should already be automatically be set by Heroku. You can make sure it is by running this in the CLI:

```
heroku config:get SECRET_KEY_BASE
```

If it's not set, you can do so by:

```
heroku config:set SECRET_KEY_BASE=$(rake secret)
```